# Show XML items from dropdown

Tags: jquery, xml, list, drop-down-menu

I've been working on a small tool for my work, but can't really get the last thing to work.

You can see the code etc. here: http://jsfiddle.net/wb157kbx/5/

What I'm trying to do is, i want the `country` from the `XML` into the dropdown, as it already are. When you select a `country`, it shows the `mobile`, `phone` and `code` data from the `XML` in the `#tal` tag. I'm making it all with JQuery.

What am i doing wrong, since i don't get the selected `price`, `phone`, `code` etc. ?

[DEMO](http://www.patrickrorth.dk/Arbejde/)

Comment: console says "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.patrickrorth.dk/Arbejde/udlandspriser.xml. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Comment: Is this from JSFiddle or the demo ?

Comment: yes JSFiddle. maybe that's your problem

Comment: look at the demo, it's working fine there

Comment: $(xml).find('item[id="' + id + '"]') where do you define the id

Comment: in the top: var id; and then in the XML Sussecc: id = $(this).attr('id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#dropdown').change(function () {     

    $selected = $('#dropdown').find(":selected");
    var id = $selected.prop("id");  
        $(xml).find('item[id="' + id + '"]').each(function ({

            var code = $(this).find('code').text();
            var fastnet = $(this).find('phone').text();
            var mobil = $(this).find('mobile').text();

        $("#pris").text("Mobil: " + mobil + " Fastnet: " + fastnet + " Landkode: " + code);

});
```

The problem is that you add a value to the global scoped id too soon.
This way your id will allways be the last id on the xml.

You need to address the selected option id

```
var id = $selected.prop("id");
```

what I would do is:

```
success: function (xml) {

            // Parse the xml file and get data
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),                
                $xml = $(xmlDoc),
                options = "";


            $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
                id = $(this).attr('id');
                land = $(this).find('country').text();
                code = $(this).find('code').text();
                fastnet = $(this).find('phone').text();
                mobil = $(this).find('mobile').text();

                options += "<option data-id='"+id +"' data-land='"+land +"' data-code='"+code +"' data-fastnet='"+fastnet +"' data-mobil='"+mobil+"' >" + land + "</option>";

            });
          $("#dropdown").html(options)

        }
```

And then on change I would do this:

```
 $('#dropdown').change(function () {       
    $selected = $('#dropdown').find(":selected");
    $("#pris").text("Mobil: " +$selected.data("mobil")+
                    " Fastnet: " +$selected.data("fastnet") + 
                    " Landkode: " + $selected.data("code"));

 });
```

Comment: Just tried the above. And it's not working. It selects the last item in the XML file when its all loaded

Comment: changed the option += ... to #dropdown with append, then it all worked. Thanks! :)